# Slice text in each container

Tags: javascript, for-loop, slice

The question is very simple for most of you here. I have the next HTML code:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <img class="post-img" src="#">
        <p class="text" id="text">Lorem500</p>
        <div class="button"></div>    
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <img class="post-img" src="#">
        <p class="text" id="text">Lorem500</p>
        <div class="button"></div>    
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

The idea is to have multiply "blog posts" with title, picture, short description, and "Read more" button. I want to have the "text" shortened from it's original text size to let's say 300 symbols. I want it to be in JS. I've tried for loop and while loop, sorry I'm new to this and can't figure it out myself.

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');

while ( content.length >= 0 ) {
  $('#text').text(function(i, txt) {
    return txt ? txt.slice(0, 300) + " ..." : txt;
  });
}
```

This may look stupid but I've tried different things, this is the last one I came with.

Hope for your help. Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) or a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop for this. Doing so would result in a never ending loop since the content length will always be over

What you need to do is say [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) the content size is over `300` you [`substring`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) it.

```
var content = "Hello this is some longer text to be cut shorter";
var displayText = ""; // The shorter version of the content

if(content.length > 5) {
    displayText = content.substring(0, 5);
} else {
    // The next is shorter then 5 so just display the text
}

console.log(displayText) // Output: Hello
```

In your case you will use `content.length > 300` and `content.substring(0, 300)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
for(var i=0;i<$('.text').length;i++){
  var el = $('.text')[i];
  if(el.innerHTML.length>300){
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.slice(0, 300) + " ...";
  }
}
```